# How can I find out how many socks strideline and happysocks sell a day?

Tags: data-request, usa

I am an MBA student looking for information for my final course.  Is there a way to find out how many socks strideline.com and happysocks.com sell per day?

Comment: You expect this kind of information to be Open Data and not trade secret? Really?

Comment: why in the world would you @jknappen expect sales daily sales data to be a trade secret? only reason i can think of is to prevent embarrassment; but really i would think they would share that stuff because they want everyone to know how important their socks are, and how many are flying off the shelves.